# Image mapping with different URL on specific pixel area

Tags: html, imagemap

I would like to add one image in website that consists of multiple links in single image. 
When end user click on particular area that need to navigate to one URL open in new tab.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Showing at least minimal effort is required on StackOverflow.

Comment: did you googled: "image map generator online"?

Comment: I was achieved this using canvas with image mapping

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dreamwaver, you can try following this link to create image mapping.
https://visibleranking.com/create-image-map-in-dreamweaver.php

Answer (score 0):

You can put div above image and add in div invisible  elements that are gonna link that part of image with something.

Or you can put your picture as a div background and do the same thing.